# How to use @FindBy annotation in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, annotations, testng, findby

I want to know what wrong with my code, because when I try to test my code, I didn´t get anything.

```
public class SeleniumTest {

private WebDriver driver;
private String nome;
private String idade;

@FindBy(id = "j_idt5:nome")
private WebElement inputNome;

@FindBy(id = "j_idt5:idade")
private WebElement inputIdade;

@BeforeClass
public void criarDriver() throws InterruptedException {

    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://localhost:8080/SeleniumWeb/index.xhtml");
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);

}

@Test(priority = 0)
public void digitarTexto() {

    inputNome.sendKeys("Diego");
    inputIdade.sendKeys("29");

}

@Test(priority = 1)
public void verificaPreenchimento() {

    nome = inputNome.getAttribute("value");
    assertTrue(nome.length() > 0);

    idade = inputIdade.getAttribute("value");
    assertTrue(idade.length() > 0);
}

@AfterClass
public void fecharDriver() {

    driver.close();

}
```

}

I´m using `Selenium WebDriver` and `TestNG`, and I tried to test some entries in `JSF` page.

Comment: what is the output you got?

Comment: The code is ok, it works for me as expected. Are you sure your `http://localhost:8080/SeleniumWeb/index.xhtml` is ok?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a difinition for @BeforeClass :

```
@BeforeClass
Run before all the tests in a class
```

And `@FindBy` is "executed" each time that you'll call the class.

Actually your `@FindBy` is called before the `@BeforeClass` so it won't work.

What i can suggest to you is to keep the `@FindBy` but let's start to use the [PageObject pattern.](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageFactory)

You keep your test's page and you create another class for your objects like :

```
public class PageObject{
  @FindBy(id = "j_idt5:nome")
  private WebElement inputNome;

  @FindBy(id = "j_idt5:idade")
  private WebElement inputIdade;

  // getters
  public WebElement getInputNome(){
    return inputNome;
  }

  public WebElement getInputIdade(){
    return inputIdade;
  }

  // add some tools for your objects like wait etc
}
```

Your SeleniumTest'll looks like that :

```
@Page
PageObject testpage;

@Test(priority = 0)
public void digitarTexto() {

  WebElement inputNome = testpage.getInputNome();
  WebElement inputIdade = testpage.getInputIdade();

  inputNome.sendKeys("Diego");
  inputIdade.sendKeys("29");
}
// etc
```

If you're going to use this tell me what's up.