# Why null pointer exception for the below code

Tags: selenium-webdriver, nullpointerexception

```
public class IbiboTest {

static WebDriver driver;

@BeforeClass
public void setUp() throws InterruptedException{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    //driver= new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.goibibo.com/");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

}


@Test
public void testIbiboHomePage(){
    IbiboHomePage home = PageFactory.initElements(driver, com.Nalini.Ibibo.IbiboHomePage.class);
    home.clickRoundTripRadioButton();

}

public class IbiboHomePage {

WebDriver driver;
@FindBy(css = "input[id='gi_roundtrip_label']")
WebElement iRoundTrip;


public IbiboHomePage(WebDriver driver){
    this.driver = driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);

}

public void clickRoundTripRadioButton(){
iRoundTrip.click();
}
```

}

I am just trying to automate ibibo website.I am getting nullpointer exception for the above code.I am not able to understand where it is passing a null value.Pls help.Thank you

Comment: what about debugging your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the following change:

1. Replace `IbiboHomePage home = PageFactory.initElements(driver, com.Nalini.Ibibo.IbiboHomePage.class);`

with `IbiboHomePage home = PageFactory.initElements(driver, IbiboHomePage.class);`

2. You can remove `static` from `static WebDriver driver;` in `public class IbiboTest`
3. In `public class IbiboHomePage` declare the instance of WebDriver as :

`WebDriver driver;`

4. From the constructor `public IbiboHomePage(WebDriver driver)` remove the line `PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);`

Execute the code and update me the status.

Comment: @Nal Did my Answer solve your Question?

Comment: Hello Yes.Thanks a lot.It soved:)

Comment: Yes,I have done that

Comment: Upvote the answer if you feel it was helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be the same problem as this previous post

[How to use @FindBy annotation in Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16508604/how-to-use-findby-annotation-in-selenium-webdriver/16512447#16512447)

Take a look about the `@findby` and `@beforeclass` execution order.